# Checking URI response code in RUBY while using a text file

Tags: ruby, file, http, response

I am trying to read data from a text file, and add it to the URI and check for status code.

Instead of

```
#Net::HTTP.start(http://somewebsite.com, 80) {|http|
# response = http.head('/testfile.html')
#  puts response.code
#}
```

I'd like to use my `|LINEfile|`

```
#Net::HTTP.start(http://somewebsite.com, 80) {|http|
# response = http.head(LINEfile)
# puts response.code
#}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What happened when you tried? Did it break? Where's the code example showing your attempt? Also, why is all your code commented out? We need working examples, showing your attempt and an explanation of what or why it didn't work for you. You can NOT use `|LINEfile|` because any variable starting with an uppercase character is a constant in Ruby. If you're reading from a file, show a minimal example of the data file and your code to read from it and pass the URL to your code.

Comment: The comments was a mistake while trying to provide an example on this site. I have parsed a txt file that contain 20 lines each containing one word.  

    File.open("test.txt", "r") do |f|
      f.each_line do |line|


now i wanna be able to use line inside http.head()

Comment: Is there a way of doing this at all?

Comment: When adding code, data, or explanations of things we'd need to know, add them to the question, not to comments. If you put the information into the question as if you'd added it initially it'll result in a more usable question. If you string them through comments then we have to read every comment and piece together the information, leading to additional opportunities to make mistakes and taking us longer to answer you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by assigning it to a variable called newURI:

```
result = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI(newURI))
puts result.code
```

Comment: This isn't really a good answer. Instead of a small snippet showing one instance of the variable, you need to show it in context. Show how you load the file, how the variable is assigned, and how the loop construct ends. Also, in Ruby, we don't use camelCase for variable names, instead we use snake_case. That's the convention, and if you ever were to release code for others to use, especially in a professional environment, you'd definitely catch trouble unless you write in an idiomatic style. This of it this way: You're leaving an answer tp help someone else in the future answer this question.